# self:: to same function name returns

Tags: php

```
public static function TestDB(){
    if (self::TestDB()){
        echo "Yes";
    }else{
        echo "No";
    }
}
```

I'm trying a form of recursion, by pushing the same variable through the the same function is something fails along the lines (do not ask why) When I do, I am presented with :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)

WHy is this *exhausting* my memory limit?

Comment: You're stuck in a recursive loop

Comment: As John said.. But if this is your entire code.. You might aswell perform a `if (function_exists(''))` until you add more code.

Comment: Yup, as @JohnConde says; the method will keep calling itself until php times out or runs out of memory

Comment: What were you trying to do by calling the same function recursively over and over again? Especially one that doesn't `return` anything? This function is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

You have recursion without a termination condition. The recursion never completes, filling the call stack and using more and more memory. You need to add a termination condition.

Here is an example of a termination condition:

```
public static function TestDB($x) {
    if ($x < 10) {
        self::TestDB($x + 1);
    } else {
        echo '>= 10!';
    }
}
```